# No Tk spawn window from Tkcon

Tags: windows, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am running the following two tutorial lines:

```
package require Tk
grid [ttk::button .b -text "Hello World"]
```

When running from a wish85 or tkcon executable I downloaded from the web, the 'Hello World' window spawns.

When I try to do it from a different Tkcon compiled into my project I dont get spawned window, and I don't get any error either.

Can someone please tell how do I make this window get spawned?

Comment: Different Tkcon compiled into your project? What do you mean with "compiled into your project?"

Comment: Tell us about how things have been built, please. This is highly likely to be the source of the problems. (Which version of Tcl and Tk are you using?)